# Is it possible to us WP Core Maintenance Mode for short pause while a plugin runs?

Tags: maintenance

I've written a plugin to manually (admin button push) delete several hundred posts that are created by another plugin.  That other plugin creates posts based on an external API.

I'm running into a situation where occasionally the API plugin is starting to creating new posts midway through the deletion.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use WP's core maintenance mode for just a few seconds to pause everything else on the site from running while the delete runs?

I've looked at update-core.php and update.php but it wasn't quite obvious to me what it was doing to initiate and terminate maintenance mode.  I was kind of hoping there was a function to set maintenance mode and another to clear maintenance mode, but I'm not seeing it.  Open to other ways to avoid this race condition as well.

Comment: @Rarst native maintenance blocks process before loading any plugin or theme. Look at the source code wp-settings.php file. Maintenance mode is checked on [55 line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L55) and plugins are loaded on [168](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L168), 175 and 209 lines. So there is no way to worry about plugins run.

Comment: @EugeneManuilov ops, my mistake! I even did take quick look at the code, I blame friday. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be easily done by creating `.maintenance` file in the root of your WordPress instance. Your script should look like this:

```
// create maintenance file before starting the long lasting process
file_put_contents( ABSPATH . '.maintenance', '<?php $upgrading = ' . time() . ';' );

// do stuff ...

// after finishing working on your stuff remove maintenance file
unlink( ABSPATH . '.maintenance' );
```

WordPress checks whether or not maintenance file exists in the root and if it does, then checks `$upgrading` variable to show maintenance message only for 10 minutes.

By default WordPress shows standard message during maintenance mode. It contains following text:

```
Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.
```

If you want to run your own script and generate unique maintenance output, then you can create `maintenance.php` file within your wp-content folder. WordPress loads that file if it exists and stops executing a process after calling the file.

Comment: I don't get preachy about these things if it's for individual use, but for distributed plugins, it would be good to use the `WP_Filesystem` methods rather than `file_put_contents()` and co. directly.

Comment: Thanks!  Super answer and just what I was looking for.  Although, Rarst's excellent insight above also means it won't quite do what I was hoping and I'll probably need to find a better way to pause the other plugin. Props you you both though!

Comment: @jb510 Rarst's insight is not so excellent as you treat it, because if native maintenance mode is enabled, then no plugins/themes are loaded and there is no need to pause anything. It means that you don't need to find better way.

Comment: @jb510 yes, sorry, never mind me - that was wrong. :)

Comment: Cool, well I used it and it seems to have done the trick in avoiding the race condition.  TY all.